# QVBoxLayout add all widgets

Tags: java, c++, qt, qlayout

I'm trying to add a number of **QLabels** into a **QVBoxLayout**:

```
QVBoxLayout *qVB = new QVBoxLayout();

QLabel *l1 = new QLabel("L 1");
QLabel *l2 = new QLabel("L 2");
QLabel *l3 = new QLabel("L 3");
QLabel *l4 = new QLabel("L 4");

qVB -> addWidget(l1);
qVB -> addWidget(l2);
qVB -> addWidget(l3);
qVB -> addWidget(l4);
```

In Java there is a much simpler approach:

```
VBox vb = new VBox();

Label l1 = new Label("1");
Label l2 = new Label("2");
Label l3 = new Label("3");

vb.getChildren().addAll(l1, l2, l3);
```

Is there anything similar in Qt\ C++ that could have me do less typping?

Comment: You can also use the Qt Designer and avoid the code, for static stuff like this it is practical, especially to set all the layouts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C++11 [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with a [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) that contains the widgets you want to add, something like this:

```
for(auto label : {l1, l2, l3})
    qVB->addWidget(label);
```

Comment: Actually l1, l2, l3 are just illustation variable names. In the app I'm writting they are `QLabel userNames`, `QLabel age`, `QLabel dOB`.

Comment: It is certainly better to use illustration variable names (`l1`, `l2`, `l3`) in this context instead of using `userNames`, `age`, `dOB` ... The question/answer should contain the least possible amount of noise. The reader should be able to get the idea without having to read all these unrelated names. . .

Comment: Having different variable names is unrelated to the question at all. Sorry, but I don't get your comment. . .

Answer (score 2):

If you're really wanting to reduce your type load something like this would do it.

```
std::vector<std::string> names = {"l1", "l2", "l3", .......};
for(std::string name : names)
    qVB->addWidget(new QLabel(name.c_str()));
```